# Changing text on label with button click

Tags: ios, ios-4.2, ios4

I want to know how we can change text on label with button click,i have 2 buttons named add and minus,if we click on add button,on each click ,it will increase from 1-10,and if we click on minus button ,it should reduce from 1-10,

I tried to do some stuff,which is below

```
-(IBAction) addQuantity
{
    for (int i=1;i<11; i++)
    {
        [m_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i]];
    }

}
```

please friends explain me how to proceed,

Regards
Ranjit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSInteger counter = 0;
-(IBAction) addQuantity
{
    if (counter > 9 )
        return;
    [m_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",++counter]];
}

-(IBAction) minusQuantity
{
    if (counter < 1 )
        return;
    [m_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",--counter]];
}
```

Comment: hey thanks beryllium,how I can set a limit to only 10 numbers?

Comment: where is m_label initialized and declared?